# How to make a 'synchronous' nodejs transform stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

Currently, I am using a transform stream named 'ChunkingStream' to receive and process data from TCP socket (and pipe to other place). The general structure is almost same as the example one given in nodejs doc:

```
ChunkingStream.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, callback) {
    // extract data from chunk
    this.push(data);
    callback();
};
```

However, since the order of data chunks matters in this problem and it looks like the call:

```
this.push(data);
```

is asynchronous.

Hence is there any method to make above call synchronous?? Cheers!

Comment: Just in case of confussion, what i meant by async is to wait until the data is actually pushed into stream.

Comment: TransformStream will not start processing the next chunk until you call the callback(). So the order is guaranteed. Also please check out this snippet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341097/does-node-js-stream-transform-maintain-the-order-of-the-chunks/42341934#42341934 I don't call this.push(data) there (data is passed via callback(null, data). But the idea is same.

Comment: `this.push(data);` is synchronous already.

Comment: Thanks! @AntonioNarkevich and @jfriend00! This did help! By the way is there any method that I can use to monitor the length of stream buffer **inside** the transform stream?

`
XXX._transform = function (chunking, encoding, callback) {
        // some method return the size of stream buffer, i.e. how many 'chunks'  
       // are wait to be executed!
}
`

Comment: "*it looks like the call `this.push(data)` is asynchronous.*" - How so? And why would that even matter for the order of the sequential processing?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your reply, since i met a problem that the *chunk* mess up by using TCP socket communication. I have checked on the client side that each packet shall be correct. So I am curious is it possible that due to some callback reasone, the packet order is not reassembled correctly at nodejs server side.

Comment: TCP takes care of order itself, so while you may find some packets out of order when inspecting them manually, the socket input will come out exactly the same on the other side.